# how to make calendar that apple made as default in swift?

Tags: swift, collectionview

I just wonder that in the calendar that apple made as default if you click day in month than view' space are split

[image]
this space change can be made by just segue??
am I have to make segue and then do the detail about height and width??
I want to get idea about this problem

you can see my project in https://github.com/shinhyogeun/Calendar.git

Comment: From [HERE](https://github.com/younatics/ExpandableCell), the idea is make tableview contain 12 months of a year, in each tableViewCell contain a collectionView, this will show date in month. When click any date in collection, you will let tableView know to expand its cell through delegate or block.

Comment: I really thanks a lot about your advice. I think I can make it real!!